# Trying to pip install on program_files and not in Appdata (Windows 10)

Tags: python, installation, pip

I installed Python on **Program Files**. The problem is that when I try to do "pip install" it does in **Appdata user** folder (I dont want that),and that means a message "this is not the path but I installed it here"

I got this on cmd

```
C:\Windows\system32>where python
C:\Program Files\Python311\python.exe
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
```

So I supose, than it is installing packages for Appdata executables (which I didn't create and dont want)

On Appdatafolder there are 3 python.exe:

```
python
python 3.7
python 3
```

Why?

How I deal with this? the only solution I have actually is surrender and reinstall on Appdata :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this?

`pip install --target=Whatever/Directory/path/You/Want`

Comment: this works thanks!  but I keep not understanding why there is a python.exe in Appdata too :S

Comment: If you download the exe for Python I believe that is the default path of download sometimes when you pip install packages I believe it defaults there as well. Best practice is to use target.